# PHP - how to upload 3 images with 3 inputs in one form php

Tags: php

I'm trying to upload 3 images to my server 
I have 3 file inputs in the same form. 
so far, I receive the following parameters through post (3 images)

```
$license_img, $car_pic, $driver_pic
```

And here I try to upload thouse images to server.

```
       if($license_img!= '') {
        $license_decoded = base64_decode($license_img);
        $license_pic_path = '....images/licenses/'.$email.'.jpg';
        file_put_contents($license_pic_path, $license_decoded);
    }

    if($driver_pic != '') {
        $driver_decoded = base64_decode($driver_pic);
        $driver_pic_path ='....images/profiles/'.$email.'.jpg';
        file_put_contents($driver_pic_path, $driver_decoded);
    }

    if($car_pic != '') {
        $car_decoded = base64_decode($car_pic);
        $car_pic_path = '....images/cars/'.$email.'.jpg';
        file_put_contents($car_pic_path, $car_decoded);
    }
```

In another script I upload one picture with **file_put_content** and it works just fine...

How is the right way to upload multiple images with one form?

### Update

```
<script>
                        function getPicture(img) {
                            var file = document.getElementById(img);
                            file.click(); // open file
                        }

                        function onImgSelected(event) {
                            var pieces = event.target.value.split("\\\");
                            var filename = pieces[pieces.length-1];
                            if(event.target.id == "driver_img") {
                                document.getElementById("path_driver_img").value = filename;
                            } else if(event.target.id == "car_img"){
                                document.getElementById("path_car_img").value = filename;
                            } else {
                                document.getElementById("path_licenta_img").value = filename;
                            }
                        }
                    </script>

                    <!-- accept="jpeg,jpg,png,bmp" -->

                    <input type="file" style="display: none" accept="jpeg,jpg,png,bmp" name="driver_img" id="driver_img" onChange="onImgSelected(event)" />
                    <input type="file" style="display: none" accept="jpeg,jpg,png,bmp" name="car_img" id="car_img" onChange="onImgSelected(event)" />
                    <input type="file" style="display: none" accept="jpeg,jpg,png,bmp" name="license_img" id="license_img" onChange="onImgSelected(event)" />

                    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 space-bottom">
                        <label class="control-label">Driver Picture</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="path_driver_img" readonly>
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-default" onClick="getPicture(\'driver_img\')" type="button">Up</button>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 space-bottom">
                        <label class="control-label">Car Picture</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="path_car_img" readonly>
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-default" onClick="getPicture(\'car_img\')" type="button">Up</button>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 space-bottom">
                        <label class="control-label">Taxi License Image <font color="red">*</font></label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="path_licenta_img" readonly>
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-default" onClick="getPicture(\'license_img\')" type="button">Up</button>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12"><br>
                    <div class="col-xs-12" align="center"> <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success btn-md"></div>
                </div>
```

Comment: check this post http://www.w3bees.com/2013/02/multiple-file-upload-with-php.html

Comment: in this example there are 1 input with multiple selection, but I have 3 inputs isn't different?

Comment: You don't show a form - why are you expecting base64 encoded _strings_?

Comment: Youre right about decoding. I use this befor because I send images from android. Now I don't decode them, I just use file_put_content but it doesnt work... :(

Comment: "doesn't work" is not helpful; your question is incomplete - e.g. show the code where you define `$license_img`

Comment: You need to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your html when you upload files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very simple script for uploading images

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file01" /><br />
    <input type="file" name="file02" /><br />
    <input type="file" name="file03" /><br />
    <input type="text" name="text" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload images" />
</form>
<?php
echo '$_FILES:'."<br /><pre>";
var_dump($_FILES);
echo "</pre>";

echo '$_POST:'."<br /><pre>";
var_dump($_POST);
echo "</pre>";
```